# Python callback with SWIG wrapped type

Tags: c++, python, swig

I'm trying to add a python callback to a C++ library as illustrated:

```
template<typename T> void doCallback(shared_ptr<T> data) {
   PyObject* pyfunc; //I have this already
   PyObject* args = Py_BuildValue("(O)", data);
   PyEval_CallObject(pyfunc,args);
}
```

This fails because data hasn't gone through swig, and isn't a PyObject.

I tried using:

```
swigData = SWIG_NewPointerObj((void*)data, NULL, 0);
```

But because its a template, I don't really know what to use for the second parameter. Even if I do hard code the 'correct' SWIGTYPE, it usually segfaults on PyEval_CallObject.

So my questions are:

1. Whats the best way to invoke swig
   type wrapping?
2. Am I even going in the right
   direction here?  Directors looked
   promising for implementing a
   callback, but I couldn't find an
   example of directors with python.

**Update:** The proper wrapping is getting generated. I have other functions that return shared_ptrs and can call those correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your update, but I guess I'm confused.  Why not just pass your shared_ptr<Foo> data to your Python function?  Why have a doCallback() at all?

Comment: My library wraps an existing c++ library. doCallback() is simply a handler that the underlying lib calls from time to time. To be clear: I never call doCallback() from python.

Comment: Ah, of course!  I've added a new answer which may serve you better.

Comment: On reflection, you can also use template metaprogramming to establish a mapping from types to SWIG type tags, leaving you with one definition of doCallback() and a bunch of behind-the-scenes machinery.  I doubt that it'd be worth your time unless you have many doCallback()-like functions, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first answer misunderstood the question completely, so let's try this again.

Your central problem is the free type parameter `T` in the definition of `doCallback`.  As you point out in your question, there's no way to make a SWIG object out of a `shared_ptr<T>` without a concrete value for `T`: `shared_ptr<T>` isn't really a type.

Thus I think that you have to specialize: for each concrete instantiation of `doCallback` that the host system uses, provide a template specialization for the target type.  With that done, you can generate a Python-friendly wrapping of `data`, and pass it to your python function.  The simplest technique for that is probably:

```
swigData = SWIG_NewPointerObj((void*)(data.get()), SWIGType_Whatever, 0);
```

...though this can only work if your Python function doesn't save its argument anywhere, as the `shared_ptr` itself is not copied.

If you do need to retain a reference to `data`, you'll need to use whatever mechanism SWIG usually uses to wrap `shared_ptr`.  If there's no special-case smart-pointer magic going on, it's probably something like:

```
pythonData = new shared_ptr<Whatever>(data);
swigData = SWIG_NewPointerObj(pythonData, SWIGType_shared_ptr_to_Whatever, 1);
```

Regardless, you then you have a Python-friendly SWIG object that's amenable to `Py_BuildValue()`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Makes sense. I was hoping there was some magic swig way to insert the SWIGType_really_long_name in my templated code, but I guess not.

Answer (score 0):

`shared_ptr<T>` for unknown `T` isn't a type, so SWIG can't hope to wrap it.  What you need to do is provide a SWIG wrapping for each instance of `shared_ptr` that you intend to use.  So if for example you want to be able to `doCallback()` with both `shared_ptr<Foo>` and `shared_ptr<Bar>`, you will need:

- A wrapper for `Foo`
- A wrapper for `Bar`
- Wrappers for `shared_ptr<Foo>` and `shared_ptr<Bar>`.

You make those like so:

```
namespace boost {
    template<class T> class shared_ptr
      {
      public:
          T * operator-> () const;
      };
  }

%template(FooSharedPtr) boost::shared_ptr<Foo>;
%template(BarSharedPtr) boost::shared_ptr<Bar>;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response David! Unfortunately I already have the code you describe, so a wrapping is getting generated.